# How to change the list of default audio codecs in Linphone

Tags: linphone

I want to set codec G729 default enabled.  I searched on StackOverflow and found many deprecated solutions, but now, they are no longer working.

I wrote some temporary (terrible) code that sets a flag every time you start the application. But I would like a normal solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the file: linphonerc

```
[audio_codec_0]
mime=G729
rate=8000
enabled=1
```

Delete your APP on iPhone or simulator, build and run.
You will found codec G729 is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

To use G729 codec you need:

1. Compile linphone with G729 support, checkout build files for the appropriate build flag
2. Change the codec list by calling [enablePayloadType](http://www.linphone.org/docs/liblinphone-javadoc/org/linphone/core/LinphoneCore.html)
3. Set it as preffered by setting it as a first one

Comment: Thank you, I have used something similar. But I was hoping to find a list of codecs by default, and change it.
Perhaps I add own solution.

Comment: As I understand it, this function returns a "dynamic"(changeable) list. But I do not understand how this list is generated for the first time. Somewhere must be prescribed default codecs in the form of some constants or build options.

Answer (score 2):

The solution, by Forced ON:

```
try {
    PayloadType ptG729 = LinphoneManager.getLc().findPayloadType("G729");
    LinphoneManager.getLc().enablePayloadType(ptG729, true);
} catch (LinphoneCoreException e) {
    Log.e(e,"Unable to modify status for codec " + "G729");
}
```

This code can be added to LinphoneActivity.java
for example, to call at the first application start

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
    if (LinphonePreferences.instance().getAccountCount() > 0) {
        LinphonePreferences.instance().firstLaunchSuccessful();
    } else {
        startActivityForResult(new Intent().setClass(this, SetupActivity.class), FIRST_LOGIN_ACTIVITY);
//Forced ON  G729
//<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    }
...
}
```